# Use Duhamel’s principle and the heat kernel to solve the initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Use Duhamel’s principle and the heat kernel to solve the initial value problem

$u_t(x, t) − ku_{xx}(x, t) = xte^{−t^2}$
$∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}, t > 0$

subject to-

$u(x, 0) = x^2 − 3x − 1$

$ ∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}.$

Im very unsure whenever I get a Duhamel’s principle question so any help will be appreciated

Comment: So, can you actually formulate Duhamel's principle?

Comment: I know it is in the form $u(x, t) = \int_{0}^{t}h(x, t − σ | σ)dσ$ but i can never get to a final answer. Could you help me? @Artem

Comment: So, what is $h$ is your formula?

Comment: Im really not sure, there no proper explanation in my lecture notes @Artem

Comment: So I would suggest for you to start googling Duhame's principle to figure out what exactly you need to do.

Comment: Wiki article [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel's_principle) is a good place to start.

Comment: Just looked it up, ive found that using the principle of superposition, we remark that the solution u to the given initial value problem for the diffusion equation may be written as $u = u^I+u^{II}$ where $u^I$ solves 
${u^I}_t(x, t) − {ku^I}_{xx}(x, t) = xt^{e−t^2} ∀t > 0 , x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ subject to $u^I(x, 0) = 0 ∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}$
and $u^{II}$ solves: 
$u^{II}t(x, t)−{ku^{II}}_{xx}(x, t) = 0 ∀t > 0 , x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ subject to $u^{II}(x, 0) = 0 ∀x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ . Am I along the right lines?? @Artem

Comment: Almost. Your $u^{II}(x,0)=f(x)$. Now you need to understand exactly what Duhamel's principle is (hint: it is related to your problem for $u^{I}$), find how to solve initial value problem for the heat equation, and you are basically done. Good luck.